# Access Form controls in different namespace and class C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a rather decent sized project and I am trying to split it up in multiple files. I am using MSVC++ 2010 as a Windows Form's application. I am trying to be able to access the form controls from the namespace and class from a user defined class in a separate file. The main autogenerated class is defined as so:

main.cpp:

```
namespace MyMainForm {
    ...
    ...
    ...
public ref class Form1: public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
    ...
    ...
};
}
```

Than I have a class I created that I want to be able to access the GUI components that are in  the Form1 class although they are "private" So I tried inherting as MyMainForm::Form1 but does not seem to work.

mynewclass.cpp:

```
class MyNewClass {
    ...
    ...
};
```

Any thoughts? Thanks for your help!

Edit:

When inherting like so:

```
class MyNewClass : MyMainForm::Form1 {
```

I get an error like this:

```
error C2654: 'MyMainForm' : is not a class or namespace name
error C2504: 'Form1' : base class undefined
```

The name of MyMainForm IS a namespace though defined in the main.cpp

Comment: What was the error message? Show a minimum example that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I edited the original post to reflect your question, thanks arne!

Comment: Ah. You defined `MyMainForm::Form1` in `main.cpp`. You'll need to move the declaration of this class to a header file which you'll need to include in `mynewclass.cpp`.

Comment: I am really not sure how you would do that since the main.cpp file is pre-generated by vc++ that contains the declaration and all the functions inside the class definition. I have a feeling moving a lot of those class functions to normal functions in main.cpp would just be a maintaining nightmare?

Comment: Yes, and it would also defy the purpose of having classes in the first place. I don't know enough about Windows Forms, especially the autogeneration, to help you further.